# Can a graph node maintain a list of references to its parents?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG implementation that works perfectly for my needs. I'm using it as an internal structure for one of my projects. Recently, I came across a use case where if I modify the attribute of a node, I need to propagate that attribute up to its parents and all the way up to the root. Each node in my DAG currently has an adjacency list that is basically just a list of references to the node's children. However, if I need to propagate changes to the parents of this node (and this node can have multiple parents), I will need a list of references to parent nodes.

Is this acceptable? Or is there a better way of doing this? Does it make sense to maintain two lists (one for parents and one for children)? I thought of adding the parents to the same adjacency list but this will give me cycles (i.e., parent->child and child->parent) for every parent-child relationship.

Comment: This is probably the best way of going about it, essentially you're building a reverse DAG to propagate changes. The question is what happens if a node's parents (or its parents and so on) connects to one of the node's children? Would the change continue to propagate infinitely?

Comment: @ardentsonata- That can't happen if the graph is a DAG, since there aren't any cycles.

Comment: @ardentsonata I'm maintaining parallel DAG's in this case, I guess. In one case, I have a DAG that is directed towards the children, eventually ending in some "leaf" nodes. This is done with the list of child references. In the other case, I have a DAG that is directed "up" towards the root, from the children. There would be no cycles in this case since each list is independently traversed.

Comment: @templatetypedef More specifically, what can't happen is a cycle, but if v is our node, c one of it's children and p a parent of the node, we can have an edge (p,c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's never *necessary* to store parent pointers in each node, but doing so can make things run a lot faster because you know exactly where to look in order to find the parents.  In your case it's perfectly reasonable.

As an analogy - many implementations of binary search trees will store parent pointers so that they can more easily support rotations (which needs access to the parent) or deletions (where the parent node may need to be known).  Similarly, some more complex data structures like Fibonacci heaps use parent pointers in each node in order to more efficiently implement the decrease-key operation.

The memory overhead for storing a list of parents isn't going to be too bad - you're essentially now double-counting each edge: each parent stores a pointer to its child and each child stores a pointer to its parent.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This is basically what I was looking for. I just wanted to know if such an approach made sense and/or had precedent.